# Image picker view not crashing not even asking for user permission, Why and How?

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller, ios11, xcode9, user-permissions, info.plist

I am working on one side project, it has image view where a user can click and select an image from the photo library. I am using UIImagePickerController.

My question is I haven't added user Permission on plist nor anywhere else. and as far I know app crashed if you don't add permission, Plus when the app opens for the first time the dialog appears asking for permission but in my case, it's not asking. 
I like to know how this can be possible or does Apple have changed something in new Xcode or OS?

I am using Version 9.2 (9C40b) and tried running the code on iPhone 6(real device iOS 11.2.6,) and in different simulator same result, I deleted the app and run it again, same no dialog.

And if Apple has changed something in iOS 11, Should we add or not the permission? whats the best way to a developer we don't want to ask, and also don't want the app to be crashed.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is YES you have to provide the description

It is mandatory to add usage description(from iOS 11) of permissions you are going to use.
Apple [states](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1937/_index.html) that

> Your app is responsible for all usage of privacy-sensitive data, including access to this data by all third-party libraries used in your app. If your app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description, your app will exit.

You will see this error in console log if permission description is not provided in Info.plist

> This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

If you try to submit the app without description for release Apple will reject it with this message

> Missing Info.plist key - This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSSpeechRecognitionUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

Summary:

If you have not provided usage description and uploaded the app earlier then your app will crash without asking for permission

If you have not provided usage description and tried to submit recently then apple will reject it.

Reference:
[Privacy Settings in iOS 10](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/privacy-settings-in-ios-10/)